# WebSocketsSharp custom events deserialize

Tags: c#, json, websocket, datamodel, websocket-sharp

I have to build a functionality where I can send custom event with `websockets-sharp`.

I made a function `MakePacket` that creates me a string like this `["draw:drawer:accept","{\"imei\":\"123\"}"]` that I can send.

```
    public string MakePacket(string eventName, string data)
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new[] { eventName, data });
    }
```

So I want to do the same in the other direction. When there is an incomming event I want to convert this back to `eventName` and `PayLoad`.

So I create a data model:

```
public class PacketModel
{
    public string EventName { get; set; }

    public string PayLoad { get; set; }
}
```

And I tried to convert this with this function:

```
    public PacketModel OpenPacket(string data)
    {
        PacketModel packet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PacketModel>(data);

        return packet;
    }
```

But this isn't working...

Does someone has an idea how I can do this?

Thank you

Comment: Instead of serializing array of `new[] {eventName, data}` - create `PacketModel` and serialize that

Comment: Oh no, how can I forgot things like this... big mistake. Thank you for the hint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create an example, how to work with `WebSocket-Sharp` and custom events like `socket.io`.

I post the example in my git repository:

[Websocket-Sharp Custom Events](https://github.com/domenicoblanko/websocketsharp_customevents)

Thanks to @Evk for the help

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
public static class sConnection
{
    public static WebSocket socket;
    public static bool connected = false;
    public static bool result = false;

    public static void Main()
    {
        socket = Connect();
        socket.Connect();


        while (!result) { }
    }

    public static WebSocket Connect()
    {
        var socket = new WebSocket(url: ""); //Your websoket enpoint

        socket.OnOpen += (sender, e) =>
        {
            isConnected = true;
        };

        socket.OnClose += (sender, e) =>
        {
            isConnected = false;
        };

        socket.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
        {
            //Converting the event back to 'eventName' and 'Json'
            PacketHandler packetHandler = new PacketHandler();
            PacketModel packet = packetHandler.OpenPacket(e.Data);

            //Do something with the message

            result = true;
        };

        return socket;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i alerady found a solution, see my post, its something simular